# How to remove unnecessary layout php includes from HTML5 template?

Tags: php, html, responsive-design

I am modifying a html5 template that includes separate layouts for mobile, smartphone, and desktop layouts. Since the desktop layout is already responsive, the mobile and smartphone layouts are unnecessary for me. The problem is that I can't find out how to disable the unneeded layouts without bringing the whole site down. Here is the code:

index.php

```
    <?php 

include "app/config.php";
include "app/detect.php";

if ($page_name=='') {
    include $browser_t.'/index.html';
    }
elseif ($page_name=='index.html') {
    include $browser_t.'/index.html';
    }
elseif ($page_name=='about.html') {
    include $browser_t.'/about.html';
    }
elseif ($page_name=='services.html') {
    include $browser_t.'/services.html';
    }
elseif ($page_name=='contact.html') {
    include $browser_t.'/contact.html';
    }
elseif ($page_name=='404.html') {
    include $browser_t.'/404.html';
    }
elseif ($page_name=='contact-post.html') {
    include $browser_t.'/contact.html';
    include 'app/contact.php';
    }
else
    {
        include $browser_t.'/404.html';
    }

?>
```

app/config.php:

```
<?php
$current_page_uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$part_url = explode("/", $current_page_uri);
$page_name = end($part_url);
$email_id = "w3layouts@gmail.com";
?>
```

app/detect.php:

```
<?php
$userBrowser = $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT']; 
if(stristr($userBrowser, 'application/vnd.wap.xhtml+xml')) 
{
$_REQUEST['wap2'] = 1;
}

elseif(stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPod"))
{
$_REQUEST['iphone'] = 1;

}
elseif(stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPhone"))
{
$_REQUEST['iphone'] = 1;

}
elseif(stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"Android"))
{
$_REQUEST['Android'] = 1;

}
elseif(stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"IEMobile"))
{
$_REQUEST['IEMobile'] = 1;

}
elseif(stristr($userBrowser, 'DoCoMo/' || 'portalmmm/'))
{
$_REQUEST['imode'] = 1;
}

elseif(stristr($userBrowser, 'text/vnd.wap.wml')) 
{
$_REQUEST['wap'] = 1;
}
elseif(stristr($userBrowser, 'text/html')) 
{
$_REQUEST['html'] = 1;
}


if(!defined('WAP'))
    define('WAP', isset($_REQUEST['wap']) || isset($_REQUEST['wap2']) || isset($_REQUEST['imode'])|| isset($_REQUEST['html'])|| isset($_REQUEST['Android'])|| isset($_REQUEST['iphone'])|| isset($_REQUEST['IEMobile']));

    if (WAP)
{
    define('WIRELESS_PROTOCOL', isset($_REQUEST['wap']) ? 'wap' : (isset($_REQUEST['wap2']) ? 'wap2' : (isset($_REQUEST['iphone']) ? 'iphone' : (isset($_REQUEST['imode']) ? 'imode' : (isset($_REQUEST['IEMobile']) ? 'IEMobile' :(isset($_REQUEST['html']) ? 'html' : (isset($_REQUEST['Android']) ? 'Android' : '')))))));  

if (WIRELESS_PROTOCOL == 'wap')
      {
$browser_t = "mobile";
      }
elseif (WIRELESS_PROTOCOL == 'wap2')
      {


$browser_t = "mobile";


      }
elseif (WIRELESS_PROTOCOL == 'imode')
      {

$browser_t = "mobile";

      }
      elseif (WIRELESS_PROTOCOL == 'iphone')
      {


$browser_t = "smartphone";

      }
      elseif (WIRELESS_PROTOCOL == 'Android')
      {


$browser_t = "smartphone";

      }
       elseif (WIRELESS_PROTOCOL == 'IEMobile')
      {

$browser_t = "smartphone";

      }
      elseif (WIRELESS_PROTOCOL == 'html')
      {

     $mobile_browser = '0';

if(preg_match('/(up.browser|up.link|mmp|symbian|smartphone|midp|wap|phone)/i',
    strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']))){
    $mobile_browser++;
    }

if((strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT']),'application/vnd.wap.xhtml+xml')>0) or 
    ((isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_WAP_PROFILE']) or isset($_SERVER['HTTP_PROFILE'])))){
    $mobile_browser++;
    }

$mobile_ua = strtolower(substr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],0,4));
$mobile_agents = array(
    'w3c ','acs-','alav','alca','amoi','audi','avan','benq','bird','blac',
    'blaz','brew','cell','cldc','cmd-','dang','doco','eric','hipt','inno',
    'ipaq','java','jigs','kddi','keji','leno','lg-c','lg-d','lg-g','lge-',
    'maui','maxo','midp','mits','mmef','mobi','mot-','moto','mwbp','nec-',
    'newt','noki','oper','palm','pana','pant','phil','play','port','prox',
    'qwap','sage','sams','sany','sch-','sec-','send','seri','sgh-','shar',
    'sie-','siem','smal','smar','sony','sph-','symb','t-mo','teli','tim-',
    'tosh','tsm-','upg1','upsi','vk-v','voda','wap-','wapa','wapi','wapp',
    'wapr','webc','winw','winw','xda','xda-');

if(in_array($mobile_ua,$mobile_agents)){
    $mobile_browser++;
    }
if (strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['ALL_HTTP']),'OperaMini')>0) {
    $mobile_browser++;
    }
        if (strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']),'iemobile')>0) {
$mobile_browser++;
}
if (strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']),'windows')>0) {
    $mobile_browser=0;
    }


if($mobile_browser>0){
   // do something wap

$browser_t = "mobile";

}
// non-mobile
else
{

$_SESSION['Browser_d'] = "web";
$browser_t = "web";

}
   } else {
   // do something else html

$_SESSION['Browser_d'] = "web";
$browser_t = "web";
   }

      }


    else
    {
$mobile_browser = '0';

if(preg_match('/(up.browser|up.link|mmp|symbian|smartphone|midp|wap|phone)/i',
    strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']))){
    $mobile_browser++;
    }

if((strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT']),'application/vnd.wap.xhtml+xml')>0) or 
    ((isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_WAP_PROFILE']) or isset($_SERVER['HTTP_PROFILE'])))){
    $mobile_browser++;
    }

$mobile_ua = strtolower(substr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],0,4));
$mobile_agents = array(
    'w3c ','acs-','alav','alca','amoi','audi','avan','benq','bird','blac',
    'blaz','brew','cell','cldc','cmd-','dang','doco','eric','hipt','inno',
    'ipaq','java','jigs','kddi','keji','leno','lg-c','lg-d','lg-g','lge-',
    'maui','maxo','midp','mits','mmef','mobi','mot-','moto','mwbp','nec-',
    'newt','noki','oper','palm','pana','pant','phil','play','port','prox',
    'qwap','sage','sams','sany','sch-','sec-','send','seri','sgh-','shar',
    'sie-','siem','smal','smar','sony','sph-','symb','t-mo','teli','tim-',
    'tosh','tsm-','upg1','upsi','vk-v','voda','wap-','wapa','wapi','wapp',
    'wapr','webc','winw','winw','xda','xda-');

if(in_array($mobile_ua,$mobile_agents)){
    $mobile_browser++;
    }
    if (strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']),'iemobile')>0) {
$mobile_browser++;
}
if (strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['ALL_HTTP']),'OperaMini')>0) {
    $mobile_browser++;
    }
if (strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']),'windows')>0) {
    $mobile_browser=0;
    }


if($mobile_browser>0){
   // do something wap

$browser_t = "mobile";

}
// non-mobile
else
{
$_SESSION['Browser_d'] = "web";
$browser_t = "web";
}

    }
     ?>
```

Basically, I need it to just display the "web" files and not any others from app/detect.php but when ever I tried commenting out what I thought wasn't needed the whole site didn't show up.

Comment: At the top of detect.php, just add `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']  = '';` so it always thinks it's a desktop browser

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @james.garriss Please pardon my ignorance but, I asked the question as clearly as I know how...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting these lines at the end of `app/detect.php`:

```
$mobile_browser = 0;
$_SESSION['Browser_d'] = "web";
$browser_t = "web";
```

That is basically replacing whatever the detection was performed with the result of detecting a desktop browser.

Answer (score 0):

Put all files and folders located in the /web/ directory to your project root path (You don't need any other file).

Edit index.html file with your favorite editor.

Search and replace **every** 'web/' with '' ex :

```
<link href="web/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
```

to

```
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
```

Do the same with all html files.

Regards.